# Support angular binding inside fineuploader template

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm starting with fineuploader and I'm currently have an issue while integrating this awesome library in my angular application.

I have some angular expressions in my template:

```
<div id="simple-previews-template" style="display: none">
  ...
  <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button small postfix">
    {{ 'ACTION.BROWSE' | translate }}
  </div>
  ...
  {{ Upload.warn }}
</div>
```

But these expressions aren't replaced at all: my browser displays `{{ 'ACTION.BROWSE' | translate }}` and `{{ Upload.warn }}` instead of their values.

I firstly thought it was due to `<script type="text/template" id="..."></script>` tag, so I changed to `<div id="..." style="display: none"></div>` without effect.

How can I have angular binding working with fineuploader?

I'm also interested in knowing why it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to say exactly how to solve your issue.  Most likely, you'll need to `$compile` the template against the proper `$scope` after it has been added to the DOM by Fine Uploader.

Also, I'm not exactly sure why you are including the template in a hidden `<div>`.  It really should be a `<script>` with a `type="text/template"`.  See our Angular example at https://github.com/FineUploader/integration-examples/tree/master/src/angularjs-nodejs.

Comment: Thank you Ray. It perfectly works. The key seems to be `$compile(element.contents())($scope);`